# Поиск набора слов в строке

Tags: javascript, поиск

Делаю фильтр сообщений в боте Телеграм. Столкнулся с такой проблемой.

У меня есть следующее:
`слова_и_фразы = ["слово0 слово1", "слово2", ("слово3" || "слово4") && ("слово5" || "слово6" || "слово7")]`

Мне нужно найти слово или слова в пришедшей строке.

Я делаю следующее:
`написанная_фраза.ИндексОф(слова_и_фразы[цикл] != -1)
{console.log("Успешно")}`

если я напишу боту - `"слово0 слово1"` - всё хорошо 
если я напишу боту - `"слово0 слово2"` - всё хорошо 
если я напишу боту - `"слово3 слово6"` или `"слово6 слово3"` - плохо 
бот реагирует на `слово3`, при этом игнорирует условие

Я новичок, сильно не ругайте

Как сделать подскажите?

Comment: боту нужна отдать стринг или булеан ? Кто парсть страку должен, клент или сервер?

Comment: что есть такое в "слове3", что заставляет бота на него так реагировать ?И кто есть бот у Вас, имя у него есть ?

Comment: @Алексей так а что боту отдавать??? есть ли какое то слово или фраза в массиве, типо труе или фолс. Или порядковый индекс в масиве, чего надо этому боту может он в обще объект ждет ?

Comment: @Алексей Только стринг боту или ему ещё колбэк нужен для работы, так значит бот это какой то метод на стороне клиента ?

Answer (score 1):

Проблему решил путём построением двойного массива (массив в под массиве). Где 0 это первые фразы, 1 это вторые фразы. Далее проверяем двумя циклами. Всем спасибо кто помогал)